# Calculate the similarity of string 1 with string 2?

Tags: java, algorithm, compare, string-comparison

I have problem with my algorithm, I tried with my sample data noted below. And I don't understand why the result is not what I thought at all. For example when i = 3(n) and j = 2(n). The q should have output 2 but it's equal to 1. I guess the cause could just be that the while loop working was having problems. But I don't know the reason why. Please someone help me! Thank you very much

[Running method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk0nw.png)

```
public static void compareStringToString(String str1, String str2) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numSames = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int p = 0, n; // p - Maximum number of similar characters, n - the number of characters of the longer string
    // str1 = "slcnsicnn"
    // str2 = "ahnscnn"
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if (str1.length() >= str2.length()) {
        n = str1.length();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    p = 0;
                    while (str1.charAt(i + p) == str2.charAt(j + p)) {
                        p++;

                        if ((i + p < n) || (j + p < str2.length())) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    numSames.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The similarity of the two strings is: " + (((float)
         Collections.max(numSames)) / n) * 100 + "%");
    else {
        n = str2.length();
        // TODO Same things
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it's really not clear what you're trying to do. I can see you're trying to calculate. Can you provide a couple of simple of two strings and how similar they are and why?

Comment: If I understood well your algorithm, then I would approach the problem totally in a different way. You detect the longest and shortest string. You try to find the shortest string in the longest. If you fail, you chunk the shortest string into two pieces (the beginning except the last char, the end except the first char) and try to look for these two. You go on until you find a match and when you find it, the length of the chunk you find is the number you're looking for

Comment: @Persixty My idea at first was to run two for loops to find 2 pairs of similar characters and then use the while loop to count the number of similar characters behind them and save it to numSames. After browsing all, get the max of numSames out. The end goal is just to get the value of p to calculate p/n to find the similarity of two strings

Comment: However, the concept of similarity here is really an opinion. In your algo you're saying that the similarity of two strings is given by the highest number of contiguous characters that are the same in the two strings. But imagine you have a string "hellohellohellohello" and another string "hellhellhellhell". Your algo will say that similarity is 4/20 (since "hell" is the highest number of contiguous chars), while for me it would have rather been 16/20 (because it happens 4 times). You should clarify the functional concept as well, I think

Comment: I'm confused by this ` if ((i + p < n) || ...`. Won't `i+p` always be < n unless i=n-1... If it's not `str1.charAt(i+p)` will be invalid!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ well maybe it will happen the way you say

Comment: In that case, my suggestion should be extended. Instead of breaking the first time you find a chunk, you should sum the length of each matched chunk and then divide that value by the length of the string. Either way, you need to provide clear examples of what you need to get some concrete help

Comment: @Persixty well Actually I've also had that happen when running the code. And that why I let p = 0 before starting the loop

Comment: The only way to solve coding problems is divide and conquer. Start by writing a method that calculates how long a match is from points in 2 strings. I'd say you're trying to do too much at once. Break the problem down.

Comment: FYI, the `char` type and `charAt` method are legacy, failing with most characters. To work with individual characters, use code point internet numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[Running Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSVRJ.png)

**

> I did as you said. I created a new method to split the work. Indeed, when I did that, my mind became clearer. And more specifically, I was able to run it smoothly without errors. Or maybe there are some more minor bugs that I haven't noticed yet. But it's really great like a little bit of a burden. Once again thank you very much for your kind advice.

**

```
// Get the number of similar characters after a pair of similar characters of 2 strings
public static int getNumSimilarAfterChar(String str1, String str2, int indexStr1, int indexStr2) {
    int numChar = 0; // It's both a count and an index
    // Substrings to work with algorithm
    String subStr1;
    String subStr2;

    if (str1.charAt(indexStr1) == str2.charAt(indexStr2)) {
        // Cut substring from highlighted part
        subStr1 = str1.substring(indexStr1);
        subStr2 = str2.substring(indexStr2);
        while (subStr1.charAt(numChar) == subStr2.charAt(numChar)) {
            numChar++;
            if ((numChar >= (subStr1.length() - 1)) || (numChar >= (subStr2.length() - 1))) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return numChar + 1;
    } else {
        return numChar;
    }
}

// Given any two strings of characters, compare the match of these two strings
/**
 * Compare the match of string 1 vs string 2
 * 
 * @param str1
 * @param str2
 */
public static void compareStringToString(String str1, String str2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numSames = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // maxSimilar - maximum number of similar characters, totalLength - the number of characters of longer string
    int numSimilar = 0, totalLength;
    // slcnsicnn
    // ahnscnn
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    // If string 1 is longer than string 2
    if (str1.length() >= str2.length()) {
        totalLength = str1.length();
        for (i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                // Browse until you come across two similar characters
                if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    numSimilar = MyStrings.getNumSimilarAfterChar(str1, str2, i, j);
                    numSames.add(numSimilar);
                    System.out.println(numSames.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        // Get the max value in a list of how many identical characters are generated           
        System.out.println("The similarity of the two strings is: " + (((float) Collections.max(numSames)) / totalLength) * 100 + "%");

    } else {
        totalLength = str2.length();
        // TODO Same things
    }
}
```